# Resize UICollectionViewCell on rotation

Tags: ios, rotation, uicollectionview

I've got a UICollectionView that takes the whole of the screen. The `UICollectionView` has cells as big as the `UICollectionView` itself, and I use paging.

On rotation of the device I want the cells to adjust their size to the new `UICollectionView` size. I currently achieve this by interchanging a layout object in `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:`:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [super willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];

    [_collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:[self collectionViewFlowLayoutForOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation] animated:YES];
}
```

with `collectionViewFlowLayoutForOrientation:` being as follows:

```
- (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)collectionViewFlowLayoutForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

    CGFloat width = UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation) ? MAX(screenSize.width, screenSize.height) : MIN(screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
    CGFloat height = UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation) ? MIN(screenSize.width, screenSize.height) : MAX(screenSize.width, screenSize.height);

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *collectionViewFlowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [collectionViewFlowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
    [collectionViewFlowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(width, height)];
    [collectionViewFlowLayout setMinimumLineSpacing:0.0f];
    [collectionViewFlowLayout setSectionInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    [collectionViewFlowLayout setMinimumInteritemSpacing:0.0f];

    return collectionViewFlowLayout;
}
```

It doesn't work as intended.

First of all, I get a message in the console indicating I probably am doing something not entirely legitimate:

```
the behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because: 
the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values.
```

It is a fair message, as starting the animation to rotate, the screen / `UICollectionView` still has the frame for the old orientation. I'd be inclined to abide it.

Secondly, the `contentOffset` is incorrect after rotation as it doesn't get recalculated.

I've seen other solutions which just invalidate the layout in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`, but this doesn't recalculate the `contentOffset` either. I followed it up by changing the `contentOffset` and `contentSize` as follows, but the result is not perfect either:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    CGSize fromCollectionViewSize = [self collectionViewSizeForOrientation:[self interfaceOrientation]];
    CGSize toCollectionViewSize = [self collectionViewSizeForOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];

    CGFloat currentPage = [_collectionView contentOffset].x / [_collectionView bounds].size.width;
    NSInteger itemCount = [_collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:0];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayoutInvalidationContext *invalidationContext = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayoutInvalidationContext alloc] init];

    [invalidationContext setContentSizeAdjustment:CGSizeMake((toCollectionViewSize.width - fromCollectionViewSize.width) * itemCount, toCollectionViewSize.height - fromCollectionViewSize.height)];
    [invalidationContext setContentOffsetAdjustment:CGPointMake(currentPage * toCollectionViewSize.width - [_collectionView contentOffset].x, 0)];

    [[_collectionView collectionViewLayout] invalidateLayoutWithContext:invalidationContext];

    [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
}
```

So, my question is: **What solution gives the intended result?**

Comment: Which ios sdk are you building your app on.

Comment: Im aware that willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration: is deprecated on iOS8, but I still support iOS7 for now.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: No, I didn't yet. In the end I think I dropped this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the line
    [_collectionView invalidateIntrinsicContentSize] just before you set your layout. This should cause it to re-calculate the layout, and, hopefully get rid of your warning message.